# Passing Arguments for custom field

Tags: joomla-3.x, jform, custom-field

I need a custom field which has to select the database with some conditions.  When customer A logged in this field has to select records belong to customer A only.

The custom field is as below

```
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

class JFormFieldGroupList extends JFormFieldList{
  protected $type='grouplist'

  public function getOptions($id=''){
    $options = array();
    //connect to database and get the records
    //Form the value and text
    return $options
  }
}
```

In the XML

```
<field name="grouplist"
  multiple="true"
  type="grouplist"          
  label="Group"/>
```

In the default.php

```
echo $this->form->renderField('grouplist',null,$default_group);
```

The question is I want to pass a value from default.php to the custom field so that I can put a conditional select query while fetching data from the database.

Comment: Instead of getting the values on the field, why don't call a method on your model to execute the query?

Comment: Pep Lainez has it correct. To do what you are trying to do you are going to have to move that to your model.

In your model create a function that will query the database using JFactory::getUser()->id

Loop through the results and format them as an option list, then return that option list and print it out in your default.php file between the select element tags

Answer (score 1):

So build it into the field logic.

```
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

class JFormFieldGroupList extends JFormFieldList{
    protected $type='grouplist'

    public function getOptions($id=''){
        $options = array();
        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        // set up your query
        $query->where('user_id = '.$user->id);
        //connect to database and get the records
        //Form the value and text
        return $options
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery onChange event and execute a controller task that will provide you a JSON result with data you need. If this is not a component you will need to create one. Alternatively you can try a CLI application. This is the only secure and reliable way.