# How to generate a dynamic note field for a custom component?

Tags: custom-component, custom-field, form-fields-types, class-extensions

I am attempting to develop my first custom component called `com_image`.  Because of the structure and function of my project requirements, it made best sense to clone the `com_contact` folder and duplicate the necessary db tables/rows.  I commented out lots of unnecessary structure from the component, but now I need to add something in.

How can I generate a blue/info [note](https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/Note_form_field_type) for the "Edit Image" (first) tab at `administrator/index.php?option=com_image&view=image&layout=edit&id=1` ?

For my project, there are actually no fields in the primary panel of the first tab.  The note field only needs to hold the `location` value which I am successfully echoing with...

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span9">
        <div class="row-fluid form-horizontal-desktop float-cols" >
            <div class="span12">
                <?php echo "Path: <b>" , $this->item->location , "</b><br>"; ?>
                <?php echo "<img src=\"" , $this->item->location , "\">"; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.edit.global', $this); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to make `$this->form->renderField();` work for me.

I read https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type/en but this only solves half of the problem.

I'd like to deliver this component with attention to [mise en place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mise_en_place) for my own education -- so please only suggest best practices.

To be more specific:

Do I create a new .php file in `com_image/models/fields` so that I can extend JFormFieldNote? If so, how do I pass my `$this->item->location` value to `getLabel()`? And how to do I call the new custom note back from edit.php? I don't want to modify `com_image/config.xml`, right?

Current screenshot:

[image]

I think GDP's answer is not quite right for my purpose: [How can I dynamically generate a form's XML from PHP?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/5469/12352)

This isn't it: [Custom 'dynamic' form field creation](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/19422/12352)

I reckon this is pretty close: [Passing Arguments for custom field](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/14229/12352)

p.s. If there is a better way to deal with the image element, I'd be happy to hear that too.

Comment: For the record, I knew it was risky to use a common/programmatical term like `image` for filenames/folders/classes/etc.  I was trying to smack together a component as a proof-of-concept.  Today I see that I have a conflict at `/plugins/editors-xtd/image/` and now I have to go back and add prefixes to **everything**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Form::setFieldAttribute()`. Typically, this is done in the model's `getForm()` method. However, if it's cosmetic only, it can be done in the view too.

In **/administrator/com_image/models/forms/image.xml** (outside of a `<fieldset>` is fine):

```
<field
    name="myNote"
    type="note"
    class="alert alert-info"
/>
```

In **/administrator/com_image/views/image/view.html.php** (just before `$this->addToolbar();`):

```
$this->form->setFieldAttribute('myNote', 'label', $this->item->location);
```

In **/administrator/com_image/views/image/tmpl/edit.php**:

```
echo $this->form->renderField('myNote');
```

---

To create a field without editing XML file:

```
$note = new \SimpleXMLElement('<field />');
$note->addAttribute('name', 'myNote');
$note->addAttribute('type', 'note');
$note->addAttribute('label', $this->item->location);
$note->addAttribute('class', 'alert alert-info');
$this->form->setField($note);
```

Comment: Yes, in `display()`.

Comment: Based on your previous comment, I think you edited the wrong XML file. `config.xml` contains component configuration form. Forms of content items are typically found in /models/forms/ directory.

Comment: I've decided to go with `description` rather than `label` because the text is better positioned vertically within the blue container via description.

Comment: I'm not going to go the "create a field without editing the XML file" way, but can you explain where to write that `$note` snippet and how that should be implemented (for future researchers' benefit)?

Comment: It's a way to dynamically add the field to the form. You'd put it wherever you manipulate the form. In this case, it's the view's `display()` method. But normally it would be in model's `getForm()` method. Or, if used in a plugin, in `onContentPrepareForm()`.