# Variables in XML form definition

Tags: jform, form, xml

I'm creating a form using the Joomla XML form definition, and I want to create a range of integer values a user can select from. The `number/integer` field is fine for this use-- but I need to allow the `first`, `last`, and `step` parameters to be set by the user of the component. Is it possible to pass in variables to the XML form?

```
<field name="myintegervalue" type="integer" default="Some integer" label="Choose an integer" description="" first="1" last="10" step="1" />
```

I realize it's possible to create a custom field type, but then I'd end up re-inventing the wheel and building the select list with the min / max / step values and duplicating the `JFormFieldNumber` code.

Comment: So in your form, before your number field you will have 3 other fields that will set the min/max/step params?

Comment: This question has been recently answered here https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/23391/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-note-field-for-a-custom-component.

Comment: @user101289 after reading the related solution that Sharky posted, if you still require support please update your question to be more specific about what you require.